# How to Bring an active anchor tag color in dynamic while loop?using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my Table[image: The table consist of three rows school, college,corporate with primary key and unique id 1,2,3]

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("select * from parent_cat order by pid ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$pid=$row['pid'];
?>
<div class="overallcopt"><a href="index.php?master=<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['p_cat'];?></a></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

1.If user click school ,school should be in active, I want to highlight school in red color and rest college and corporate should in black color,
     2.If user click college ,college should be in active, I want to highlight college in red color and rest  school and corporate should in black color,
     3. Like wise for corporate,

Comment: create a class in css and than use: `$active = ($_GET['master'] == $row['pid'] ? 'class="activeClass"' : '');`

Comment: but if any body click on anything, like School, than it will redirect to master.php file,,,, is it same file?

Comment: No,It will redirect to index.php only,   can write for me? I have tried lot and frustrated .now I need your help I put all condition like if($_GET['master']=='1') <a href="index.php?master=<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $row['p_cat'];?></a>

Comment: file is same??? this code written in index.php...

Comment: Yes,That is the same file, You can see in live also http://yesservice365.com/, I got struck where to put if condition in while loop,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, you can add active class on anchar as:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $active = (intval($_GET['master']) == $row['pid'] ? 'class="active"' : '');
    ..........
```

Use this variable in your HTML:

```
<a <?=$active?> href="index.php?master=<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['p_cat'];?></a>
```

**Side Note:**

Please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` its deprecated and not available in PHP 7.

Comment: Thanks. I got your point but where to user mysql_* in my above code, I am to this line mysqli_* or PDO instead of mysql_*

Comment: @webResource: friend, u r using mysql_query() i suggest to use mysqli_query because mysql_query is deprecated and close in php 7

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $sql=mysql_query("select * from parent_cat order by pid ");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $pid=$row['pid'];
?>
        <div class="overallcopt" style="background-color:<?php if(isset($_GET['master']) && $_GET['master']==$row['pid']){echo "red";}else{echo "black";} ?>;"><a href="index.php?master=<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['p_cat'];?></a></div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Try this